# Return one object insted of array of objects using map function [codesandbox]

Tags: javascript, node.js, functional-programming, map-function

CodeSandbox example
https://codesandbox.io/s/throbbing-worker-8s68n?file=/src/index.js

So I have an object and I'm updating the key name by removing the __number, I want to move the the 1st key [ 694 & 695 ] to inside the object as id = 694. I didn't manage to make that happen cause I get a new object for each key value ( see code below ).

```
var options = 
{
    "694": {
        "title_694": "Tiger",
        "category_694": "848",
        "description_694": "long description"
    },
    "695": {
        "title_694": "Turtles",
        "category_694": "347",
        "description_694": "long description"
    }
}
```

and here is my code

```
Object.keys(options).map( value => (
      {
        [value] : Object.keys(options[value]).map((keyName) => (
              {[keyName.replace(/_*\d+/g, '')] : options[value][keyName]}
            )) 
      }
  )
)
```

it output as below

```
[
    {
        "694": [
            {
                "title": "Tiger"
            },
            {
                "category": "848"
            },
            {
                "description": "long description"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "695": [
            {
                "title": "Turtles"
            },
            {
                "category": "347"
            },
            {
                "description": "long description"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

How can make it work to output as below

```
[
    {
        "id": 694,
        "title": "Tiger",
        "category": "848",
        "description": "long description"
    },
    {
        "id":695,
        "title": "Turtles",
        "category": "347",
        "description": "long description"
    }
]
```

Comment: @Andreas so how do I tell him to not do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using forEach without changing the key names in the original object

```
var result = [];
Object.keys(options).forEach((element) => {

  const item = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(options[element]).map(([k, v]) => {
      k = k.replace(/_*\d+/g, "");
      return [k, v]
    })
  )
  result = [...result,{ id: element, ...item }]
  // Or you could use push which is slightly faster
  // To see benchmarks Google Spread operator vs push site: measurethat.net
  // result.push({ id: element, ...options[element] });
});

document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = `<pre>${JSON.stringify(
  result,
  null,
  4
)}</pre>`;

console.log(result);
```

The output

```
[
    {
        "id": "694",
        "title": "Tiger",
        "category": "848",
        "description": "long description"
    },
    {
        "id": "695",
        "title": "Turtles",
        "category": "347",
        "description": "long description"
    }
]
```

Comment: I'm curious, why did you opt for unpacking and rebuilding the entire array each time instead of using `push`? Your `result = [...result, {OBJ}]` line could be a lot quicker and more efficient with an older bit of functionality `result.push({OBJ})`. Take a look at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Comment: @SEoF Just didn't think about it lol, but they're pretty much the same just google Spread operator vs push site: measurethat.net. though I'll update my answer to include the fastest way "PUSH".

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do it without map :

```
var result = [];
Object.keys(options).forEach((element) => {
  result.push({ id: element, ...options[element] });
});
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "id": "694",
        "title_694": "Tiger",
        "category_694": "848",
        "description_694": "long description"
    },
    {
        "id": "695",
        "title_694": "Turtles",
        "category_694": "347",
        "description_694": "long description"
    }
]
```

Ask me if you have more questions.
But you need more code to remove id from new keys object

Comment: Thanks, But how to I implement the key name change? removing the number?

Comment: Why remove `.map()` to then write your own `.map()`?

Comment: as you have "keyname_id", you can use String.prototype.split() with "_" as separator and take the first element

Comment: @Chiquito_Sensei could you please update your answer 

Answer (score 0):

Personally like you, I prefer not to manually build a whole new array.

```js
var options = {
    "694": {
        "title_694": "Tiger",
        "category_694": "848",
        "description_694": "long description"
    },
    "695": {
        "title_694": "Turtles",
        "category_694": "347",
        "description_694": "long description"
    }
}

let mutated = Object.values(Object.entries(options).map(([id, option]) => {
    return Object.assign({
        id: id,
    }, Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(option).map(([key, value]) => {
        return [key.replace(/_*\d+$/g, ''), value];
    })));
}));
```

This lets the first `map` function create a new array accordingly, `Object.assign` ensures you have a single object from each, and the `Object.entries` and `Object.fromEntries` to convert to an array of pairs to then convert the keys, and then back from the array of pairs.

Have a read of the MDN documentation relating to `Object.entries`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

That links to the `Object.fromEntries` documentation, too.

As a side note, I've modified your regular expression to include the end-of-line match so it will modify something like `w3tag_694` in the expected way. I would also suggest looking at changing the `*` in the regex to a `+` to be a little stricter.

There is a caveat: `fromEntries` is a relatively new feature, but is supported by all major browsers still supported by their makers. Check the support: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries#browser_compatibility